# Linking issues with libjpeg

Tags: compiling, gcc, linker

I have a game I'm writing which recently required libjpeg. I wrote some code using libjpeg on some-other-machine and it worked as expected. I pulled the code to this machine and tried compiling and running it and have been getting the runtime error out of libjpeg:

> `Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80`

If I use ldd to see what the binary is linked to, I get:

> `ldd Debug/tc | grep jpeg`
>   libjpeg.so.62 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 (0x00007f50f02f2000)

My compile flags include -ljpeg. The current jpeg related shared objects in my /usr/lib looks like this:

```
find | grep jpeg | xargs ls -l --color
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  61256 2011-09-26 15:43 ./gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5912 2011-10-01 06:40 ./grub/i386-pc/jpeg.mod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  40264 2011-08-24 05:41 ./gstreamer-0.10/libgstjpegformat.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  78064 2011-08-24 05:41 ./gstreamer-0.10/libgstjpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17920 2011-09-27 17:30 ./i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-jpeg.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 2011-08-10 14:07 ./i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 145068 2011-08-10 14:07 ./i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  30440 2011-09-30 05:25 ./i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    924 2011-06-15 05:05 ./ImageMagick-6.6.0/modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39504 2011-06-15 05:05 ./ImageMagick-6.6.0/modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10312 2011-06-03 00:18 ./imlib2/loaders/jpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43072 2011-10-21 19:11 ./jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23184 2011-10-14 02:46 ./kde4/jpegthumbnail.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132632 2009-04-30 00:24 ./libopenjpeg-2.1.3.0.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 2009-04-30 00:24 ./libopenjpeg.so.2 -> libopenjpeg-2.1.3.0.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  23224 2011-08-03 04:20 ./libquicktime2/lqt_mjpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27208 2011-08-03 04:20 ./libquicktime2/lqt_rtjpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  47800 2011-09-24 10:12 ./strigi/strigiea_jpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3091 2011-05-18 05:25 ./syslinux/com32/include/tinyjpeg.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  22912 2011-09-27 17:38 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-jpeg.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 226798 2011-08-10 14:06 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    935 2011-08-10 14:06 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 2011-08-10 14:06 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     17 2011-10-15 10:50 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62 -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 150144 2011-08-10 14:06 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 2011-10-15 10:50 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 -> libjpeg.so.8.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 2011-11-30 01:25 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8.3.0.bak -> ./libjpeg.so.62.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  31488 2011-09-30 05:13 ./x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
```

The original machine runs Gentoo, 'this' machine runs Ubuntu 11.10. Both are 64-bit. The gentoo box only has libjpeg version 8, it seems.

Ultimately, my question is: **How can I resolve this?** I'd also like to know how I can determine exactly which library the linker has used.

EDIT: My game also links to SDL_image, which according to ldd, links to libjpeg version 8. I bet this is where my troubles stem from. How can I tell gcc to link my game to libjpeg version 8? I tried -l/usr/lib/libjpeg.so.whatever and it complained about not finding the specified lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Refer to these useful links as well:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html

Comment: Thanks, these are good reads. See my edit above -- I think I've narrowed down the issue. I don't think setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is necessary, and your second link provides some compelling reasons not to do so anyway.

Comment: Intendedly chose to add the second link, emphasising on when not to use the variable. Seems you've figured.

Comment: btw, if you are sure of the library path of libjpeg, would not mind trying with  -Wl,-rpath,$(LIB_PATH) option of gcc and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Following link solved the issue for me. [How do you link to a specific version of a shared library in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828053/how-do-you-link-to-a-specific-version-of-a-shared-library-in-gcc)

Excerpt from the link that helped me-

***Instead of using "-lcurl" use "-l:libcurl.so.3" And ofcourse also use "-L _installed_path_"***

My error was the reverse- "Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62"

To find out which jpeg library my binary was linked against, I did-

```
ldd my_binary | grep jpeg
```

output was-

```
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
```

Clearly, the binary was depending on libjpeg8 (library 80), which was why I was getting the error.

To find out if I really had libjpeg62 in my system, I did

```
ldconfig -p | grep jpeg
```

output was-

```
libplayerjpeg.so.3.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libplayerjpeg.so.3.0
libopenjpeg.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libopenjpeg.so.2
libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so.62
libjpeg.so.62 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.62
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libjpeg.so.8 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8
libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so
libjpeg.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
```

So in my case, instead of just using -ljpeg, I used this (in the make file)-

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -l:libjpeg.so.62
```

Don't forget to replace **#include (jpeglib.h>** in your cpp file with

```
extern "C" {
#include "jpeglib.h" }
```